# Filter on Join but still return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im not sure exactly how to explain this. The best i can explain it is that i want to do something similar to a Left Join, only i want to return a subset of the main table matching criteria of the joined table, but still return all left joined rows. I hope that makes some sort of sense.

I have 4 tables:

Company

Services

ServicesTranslations

CompanyService

A Company can have many Services and a Service can have many Translations.
I want to filter on the ServiceTranslation table for a given search term.

The only way i can get this to work is in the SQL below, but i feel perhaps there is a better more cleaner way to do this, or is my solution ok?

```
        DECLARE @defaultLanguage NVARCHAR(5)

        SET @defaultLanguage = (SELECT LanguageCode FROM LANGUAGE WHERE IsDefault = 1)

        SELECT
            c.Id,
            c.Name,
            c.OrgNr,
            c.UserId,
            c.Address,
            c.PostalArea,
            c.County,
            c.Country,
            c.Description,
            c.DescriptionFull,
            c.Telephone,
            c.Email,
            c.Website,
            c.IsApproved,
            s.Id,
            ISNULL(tr.Name, def.Name) Name

          FROM Company c

          INNER JOIN CompanyService cs on cs.CompanyId = C.Id

          INNER JOIN Service s on s.Id = cs.ServiceId 

          LEFT OUTER JOIN ServiceTranslation tr
            ON s.Id = tr.ServiceId AND tr.LanguageCode = @userLanguage
          -- join default language of the service:

          LEFT OUTER JOIN ServiceTranslation def
            ON s.Id = def.ServiceId AND def.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage 

          WHERE c.IsApproved = 1 

          AND
          c.Id IN 
          (
              SELECT c1.Id FROM Company c1

              INNER JOIN CompanyService cs1 on cs1.CompanyId = c1.Id

              INNER JOIN Service s1 on s1.Id = cs1.ServiceId 

              INNER JOIN ServiceTranslation tr1
                ON s1.Id = tr1.ServiceId AND tr1.LanguageCode = @userLanguage
              -- join default language of the service:

              INNER JOIN ServiceTranslation def1
                ON s1.Id = def1.ServiceId AND def1.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage



               AND s1.IsApproved = 1 AND  ISNULL(tr1.Name, def1.Name) LIKE '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
          )
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I think some clarification is required. Im not sure how to add the table data in a readable format so i have attached some images of the tables and desired results.

Company Table:

[image]

Service Table:

[image]

ServiceTranslation Table:

[image]

CompanyService Table:

[image]

Desired Results (@userLanguage = 'nb-NO' and @searchquery = 'Transport'):

There are two companies that have a Service with the word 'Transport' in. I want these two companies returned plus all their other services.

[image]

As you can see from the result image, im filter companies that have a matching service, but still want to return those matching companies and all of their services.

I hope this makes it a bit more clear :)

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would really help.  What subset do you want to return?

Comment: You're missing a comma after the s.Id in the main SELECT statement  => ` c.Website, c.IsApproved, s.Id, ISNULL(tr.Name, def.Name) Name`

Comment: @J.D. Sorry that was a typo, I've fixed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTE:

```
;WITH Comps AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c.CompanyId FROM CompanyService  C 
    LEFT JOIN  ServiceTranslation tr ON tr.ServiceId = C.ServiceId AND tr.LanguageCode = @userLanguage AND tr.Name LIKE '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
    LEFT JOIN ServiceTranslation def ON def.ServiceId = C.ServiceId AND def.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage AND def.Name LIKE '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
    WHERE tr.ServiceId IS NOT NULL OR def.ServiceId IS NOT NULL
)

    SELECT
        c.Id,
        c.Name,
        c.OrgNr,
        c.UserId,
        c.Address,
        c.PostalArea,
        c.County,
        c.Country,
        c.Description,
        c.DescriptionFull,
        c.Telephone,
        c.Email,
        c.Website,
        c.IsApproved,
        s.Id,
        def.Name

      FROM Company c

      INNER JOIN CompanyService cs on cs.CompanyId = C.Id

      INNER JOIN Service s on s.Id = cs.ServiceId 

      INNER JOIN ServiceTranslation def ON def.ServiceId = s.Id AND def.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage

      INNER JOIN Comps CM ON CM.CompanyId = c.Id

      WHERE c.IsApproved = 1 AND s.IsApproved = 1
```

OR with a subquery:

```
SELECT
            c.Id,
            c.Name,
            c.OrgNr,
            c.UserId,
            c.Address,
            c.PostalArea,
            c.County,
            c.Country,
            c.Description,
            c.DescriptionFull,
            c.Telephone,
            c.Email,
            c.Website,
            c.IsApproved,
            s.Id,
            def.Name

          FROM Company c

          INNER JOIN CompanyService cs on cs.CompanyId = C.Id

          INNER JOIN Service s on s.Id = cs.ServiceId 

          INNER JOIN ServiceTranslation def ON def.ServiceId = s.Id AND def.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage

          INNER JOIN Comps CM ON CM.CompanyId = c.Id

          WHERE c.IsApproved = 1 AND s.IsApproved = 1 AND c.Id IN 
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT c.CompanyId FROM CompanyService  C 
            LEFT JOIN  ServiceTranslation tr ON tr.ServiceId = C.ServiceId AND tr.LanguageCode = @userLanguage AND tr.Name LIKE '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
            LEFT JOIN ServiceTranslation def ON def.ServiceId = C.ServiceId AND def.LanguageCode = @defaultLanguage AND def.Name LIKE '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
            WHERE tr.ServiceId IS NOT NULL OR def.ServiceId IS NOT NULL
          )
```

Comment: I tried that already but that only returns me the companies and service rows that match the search parameter. I have added some more details to explain what im after. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there had to be a cleaner way to do it! This was very insightful !